# Visual Studio 15 2017 and cmake release builds

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am try to convert our visual studio builds to use cmake. For the most part it's working; the debug build works like a champ! But when I try to create a "release" build, a "Debug" directory is created inside the build/release directory.

```
C:\repos\source\build\Release\Debug>ls

dep1.dll  dep1.ilk  dep1.pdb  test.pdb  dep2.pdb
dep1.exp  dep1.lib  test.lib  dep2.lib
```

Why is the compiler creating a Debug  directory inside the release directory? It looks bad, I don't want there to be any confusion between debug and release! Putting a "Debug" directory inside the release directory looks "hacky" to me.

The first dependency and test library are built successfully but the libraries and test executables are dumped inside "release/Debug" directory, not inside the "build/release" directory. Because upper level dependencies are linking inside the "build/release", I expect to find all build artifacts in the "build/release" directory.

In my CMakeLists.txt, I set the CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY to build/Release. This is created and used, but like I said earlier, a Debug directory is created and is used to put all built targets. See snippet of proj1.cmake

```
function(SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES build_path build_type)

  MESSAGE ( "SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES: building as ${build_type}")

  if( build_type STREQUAL "Debug" )

    SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
    SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
    SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
 SET(VS_INTERMEDIATE_DIRECTORY_DEBUG} ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} )

  elseif( build_type STREQUAL "Release" )

    SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
    SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
    SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
  SET(VS_INTERMEDIATE_DIRECTORY_RELEASE} ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} )

  endif()

endfunction( SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES )

function(SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES_1 build_path build_type)

  MESSAGE ( "SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES: building as ${build_type}")

  SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
  SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
  SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)
  SET(CONFIG_DIR ${build_path}/${build_type} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction( SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES )
```

Snippets of CMakeLists.txt

```
SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES_1(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

# Executable we want cmake to build
add_executable(proj1  ${SRC} ${HDR} )

ADD_DEPENDENCIES( proj1 dep1 dep4)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( proj1 ${dep1} ${dep2} ${dep3} ${dep4} )

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( proj1 PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( proj1 debug ${LIBD}     optimized ${LIB}      )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(proj1 debug ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG} optimized ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( proj1  debug ${Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG}  optimized ${Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( proj1 debug ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG}     optimized ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE}    )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( proj1 debug ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG}     optimized ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE}    )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( proj1 debug ${Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG}     optimized ${Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE}    )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( proj1 debug ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY_DEBUG}      optimized ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY_RELEASE}     )
```

Has anyone ever experienced this? I googled stuff for cmake and visual studio, and set vs_intermediate_directory_release to the same path as cmake_library_output_directory. But it doesn't do anything different; It still creates this debug directory inside the build/release directory.

Is this something we cannot change via cmake? Why is this so hard to do, I've been banging my head against this problem for a really long time...any help is help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to use the configuration specific versions of the CMake variables, i.e. `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE`

Comment: You attempted to *describe the code*, but that description is very *vague*. Instead, **show the code** (add the code into the question post).

Comment: Well, How are building the "release".  Are you switching to "Release" in Visual Studio?  Otherwise there shouldn't ever be a "Debug" directory created.

Comment: @vre I tried that too, but it still creates the superfluous build/release/Debug directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev sorry for the vagueness, I updated with some code snippets. Hope it's more informative.

Comment: @fred when I run cmake via the command,  `cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` that's the only way I specify. in the function `SET_OUTPUT_DIRECTORIES` it has a conditional statement.

Comment: Oh, you use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable in Visual Studio, which is **multiconfiguration** generator. Do not do that, neither set the variable nor read it: `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` **variable means nothing** in such generators, see [its documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html). Instead, set **both** `_DEBUG` and `_RELEASE` flavors of `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_* `variable **unconditionally**. When Visual Studio will choose build type, it will automatically read the directory from the appropriate flavor of the variable.

Comment: If you are building via the command line you can use something like 'cmake --build <dir> --config Release' to build the Release version of the targets. The project file created by CMake is for all build types and you need to build the correct one.